# .NET 6 ActiveMQ(Masstransit) message consumed only once using Redis

Tags: c#, .net, redis, activemq-classic, consumer

I need to do a task. There is a producer and consumer in C# using ActiveMQ(Masstransit). You know activeMQ is "at least once" system" and I need somehow to make sure that single message is consumed only once(exactly once). How can I achieve this using Redis? I have got an idea in cosumer to check if key exists in Redis if not then proceed consuming message and send key to cache. Otherwise throw an exception. But I am not sure if this will work, because latency happens. What would be better approach to implement this? I am also not sure which values I should pick up for sliding and absolute time.

Thanks!

Here is code block of current situation in consumer.

```
                double? absoluteExpireSecs = EnvironmentVariablesHelper.GetDoubleValue("redis_absolute_expire_seconds");
                double? slidingExpireSecs = EnvironmentVariablesHelper.GetDoubleValue("redis_sliding_expire_seconds");

                if (await _redisService.Exists(context.Message.Id.ToString(), "1", true, absoluteExpireSecs, slidingExpireSecs) == true)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Key: {context.Message.Id} already exists in cache");
                }

                _logger.Information("Key: {Key} does not exist in cache. Proceeding...", context.Message.Id);
```

RedisService

```
        public async Task<bool> Exists(string key, string data, bool setIfDoesNotExist = true, double? absoluteExpireTimeSecs = null, double? slidingExpireTimeSecs = null)
    {
        string cachedRecord = await GetRecord(key);

        if (cachedRecord == null)
        {
            if(setIfDoesNotExist == true)
            {
                SetRecord(key, data, absoluteExpireTimeSecs, slidingExpireTimeSecs);
            }

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would not work as described, as you need the `Check if message exists` and the `Set message as read` operations to be atomic to avoid a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Otherwise it could happen that you check for the message existence twice because the `Set message as read` operation has not yet completed before the second `Check if message exists` operation has completed.

Redis has some commands that you could use though. One option would be to use  the [`SET`](https://redis.io/commands/set/) command with the `NX` or `XX` parameter, which only set the value if it already exists (= `XX`) or not exists (= `NX`). You can then check the return value of the operation and act accordingly:

Here an except from the docs regarding the return value:

> Null reply: (nil) if the SET operation was not performed because the user specified the NX or XX option but the condition was not met.

That means if you get a null reply using the option `NX` you know the message was already consumed.